# Problem when defining function through NIntegrate and NDSolve and Interpolation - Bug?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, interpolation, differential-equations

More than a single question, I have some doubts about the output of certain functions when defined through the result of other calculations. I am an active user of Mathematica, but maybe I haven't read deeply enough about Attributes or related things. Here is the following minimal example:

```
{tini, tfin} = {-Log[100], 0};
firstFuncK=NDSolve[{D[f[t,k],t]+f[t,k]^2+(1-t)*f[t,k]==3/2*
(1+k^2),f[tini,k]==1},f,{t,tini,tfin},{k,0.001,10}]

secondFuncK[t_?NumberQ, k_] := 
Exp[NIntegrate[f[et, k] /. firstFuncK, {et, tini, t}]]

thirdFuncK[t_,k_]:=Log[N[secondFuncK[t,k]/secondFuncK[-Log[100],k]]][[1]]
```

Here comes the first question, why exactly do I need the `[[1]]` or `First` and the `N`. Without them I get:

```
thirdFuncK[-1,0.01]
{Log[4.11782/secondFuncK[-Log[100],0.01]]}
```

It is weird that Mathematica doesn't output a number, since secondFuncK is already numerical.

And I don't understand why I get a List in this case:

```
thirdFuncLin[et_]=thirdFuncK[et,0.01];
```

Output:

```
thirdFuncLin[-1]
{1.41532}

Plot[thirdFuncLin[tt],{tt,-4,0}]
```

[image: thirdFuncK]

But the real problem is when I use this function to interpolate:

```
thirdInterp=Interpolation[Table[{et,thirdFuncLin[et][[1]]},{et,-Log[100],0,0.01}]]
```

I get a completely different result:

```
Plot[thirdInterp[tt], {tt, -4, 0}]
```

[image: thirdInterp]

I know there are related questions of simple mistakes people do, but I haven't found anything that helps me really to understand the core of this problem.

Thanks for any suggestions also on style or optimization.

Comment: You should include the definitions of `tini`, `tfin` in your question -- I guessed below.

Comment: you're right, done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

The problem is subtler than my first analysis revealed.  There is indeed a problem with the variable `et` in `NIntegrate` not being properly blocked.  Part of the problem has to do with the extra braces in `firstFuncK` which has the form

```
{{f -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]}}
```

Somehow that leads to an evaluation of `et` in the integrand `f[et, k] /. firstFuncK` in the definition of `secondFuncK`. This may be observed in the following minimal example, in which `x` plays the role of the OP's `et`:

```
g0 = {{g -> (#^2 &)}};
fn[x1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x] /. g0, {x, 1, x1}]

Table[fn[x], {x, 4}]
fn /@ Range@4
(*
  {{0.}, {4.}, {18.}, {48.}}
  {{0.}, {2.33333}, {8.66667}, {21.}}
*)
```

The outputs are the same if we define `g0 = First @ {{g -> (#^2 &)}}`.  This happens V8/9/10.

A consequence is that the bug could be avoided with using `First` on `NDSolve`:

```
{tini, tfin} = {-Log[100], 0};
firstFuncK = First @ NDSolve[{
   D[f[t, k], t] + f[t, k]^2 + (1 - t)*f[t, k] == 3/2*(1 + k^2), f[tini, k] == 1}, 
   f, {t, tini, tfin}, {k, 0.001, 10}]
secondFuncK[t_?NumberQ, k_] := Exp[NIntegrate[f[et, k] /. firstFuncK, {et, tini, t}]]
thirdFuncK[t_, k_] := Log[N[secondFuncK[t, k]/secondFuncK[-Log[100], k]]]
thirdFuncLin[et_] = thirdFuncK[et, 0.01]
thirdInterp = Interpolation[Table[{et, thirdFuncLin[et]}, {et, -Log[100], 0, 0.01}]]
```

### The problem and a fix

The problem arises because of the use of `et` as a variable in `NIntegrate` and as the iterator symbol in `Table`.  `Table` effectively uses `Block` to set the value of `et`.  This interferes with `NIntegrate`.  You can either use a different variable or protect `et` by using `Block` like this:

```
secondFuncK[t_?NumericQ, k_] := 
 Block[{et}, Exp[NIntegrate[f[et, k] /. firstFuncK, {et, tini, t}]]]
```

With this definition, we get

```
thirdInterp = (* needs reevaluation *)
 Interpolation[Table[{et, thirdFuncLin[et][[1]]}, {et, -Log[100], 0, 0.01}]];

Plot[thirdFuncLin[tt], {tt, -4, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Original analysis of the problem

Keep the OP's definitions for testing.

Below we see that blocking `et` makes a difference and yields the same result as `Table`:

```
Block[{et = -0.`}, thirdFuncLin[et]]
(* {3.34341} *)

Block[{x = -0.`}, thirdFuncLin[x]]
(* {2.03644} *)

Table[thirdFuncLin[et], {et, {0.}}]
(* {{3.34341}} *)
```

Where the `3.34341` comes from.  The integrand `f[et, 0.01]` of `NIntegrate` evaluates to `f[0, 0.01]`, which is then integrated.  Since this is constant, we can check by hand as follows:

```
{tini, tfin} = {-Log[100], 0}; (* omitted by OP from Q *)
f[et, 0.01]*(0 - tini) /. firstFuncK /. et -> 0.
(* {3.34341} *)
```

### Comment: Bug?

This appears to be a bug in V10/V9/V8.  The docs for[`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html) state

> `NIntegrate` has attribute `HoldAll` and effectively uses `Block` to localize variables.

This does not happen here.  Confirmation would be appreciated.

### Edit - The minor problems

I was so focused on the potential bug that I forgot about the OP's other issues.

The solution returned by `NDSolve` has the form of a `List` of a solutions, each solution being itself a `List` of substitution rules, one `Rule` for each variable.  In the OP's case, it has the form

```
{{f -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]}}
```

When this is used with [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`./` -- see the last "Basic Example" in the documentation), you get a list:

```
f /. {{f -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]}}    
(* {InterpolatingFunction[<>]} *)
```

It would be nicer to get just the function without the list.  To do that, knowing there is only one solution, one define `firstFuncK` like this with [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html),

```
firstFuncK = First @ NDSolve[<etc>]
```

or like this (V9+) with[`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html),

```
firstFuncK = NDSolveValue[<etc>]
```

That removes the need for `[[1]]` in later definitions and makes `thirdFuncLin` evaluate to a number instead of a `List`; this is because using `firstFuncK` with `ReplaceAll` results in a function, not a list:

```
f /. firstFuncK
(* InterpolatingFunction[<>] *)
```

Next, `N` needs to be used because the OP used the [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) [`_?NumberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberQ.html) instead of [`_?NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html).  The difference is that `-Log[100]` is a numeric expression, but not technically a number, which is one of `Integer`, `Rational`, `Real`, or `Complex`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for all your comments and suggestions. So, if I understand right, using `Block` should give me the right result or otherwise using `First` before `NDSolve`. But this shouldn't be necessary since `NIntegrate` should localize all variables and this is the bug right?

Comment: @Sanit That's right.  (I may reorganize the answer when I have time.  The two major edits have resulted in a somewhat disorganized answer and there are some ungrammatical or unclear bits.)

Comment: Great, thanks! What I still don't understand from your minimal example is the difference between `Table[fn[x], {x, 4}]` and `fn /@ Range@4`. Why do they give different results?

Comment: `Table` effectively uses `Block` to set `x` equal to 1, 2, 3, 4 in turn; the bug allows the symbol `x` in the integrand of `NIntegrate` to be replaced by the numerical value *before* the integration.  So `NIntegrate` integrates a constant; e.g. when `x = 4`, it calculates `NIntegrate[{4^2}, {x, 1, 4}]`.  `fn /@ Range@4` calculates `fn[1]`, `fn[2]`, etc., without changing `x`.  `fn[4]` calculates `NIntegrate[{x^2}, {x, 1, 4}]`.  The `Table` behavior can be imitated by `Block[{x = #}, fn[x]] & /@ Range@4`.

Answer (score 4):

Two small changes make this work in a much nicer way:

First, the use of `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve` gets rid of this rule replacement monkey business.

```
{tini, tfin} = {-Log[100], 0};
firstFuncK = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[f[t, k], t] + f[t, k]^2 + (1 - t)*f[t, k] == 
    3/2*(1 + k^2), f[tini, k] == 1}, 
  f, {t, tini, tfin}, {k, 0.001, 10}]
(* InterpolatingFunction[....] *)
```

This then makes the second and subsequent functions much cleaner:

```
secondFuncK[t_?NumericQ, k_] := 
 Exp[NIntegrate[firstFuncK[et, k], {et, tini, t}]]

thirdFuncK[t_, k_] := 
 Log[secondFuncK[t, k]/secondFuncK[-Log[100], k]]

thirdFuncLin[et_] = thirdFuncK[et, 0.01];

thirdFuncLin[-1]
(*1.415323046633079`*)

Plot[thirdFuncLin[tt], {tt, -4, 0}]
```

Note, the additional change: I replaced the `_?NumberQ` with a `_?NumericQ` since `Log[100]` is not a number (it's a symbolic expression) but it is a numeric quantity. That's also the reason why the `N` was needed; it forces the `Log[100]` to be `_?NumberQ`.